# Static IP on Google cloud instance stopped working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a second static IP for a google cloud instance. Everything was fine for a number of months.

The instance will no longer receive traffic externally. I can reach the IP from the server - but nothing is available from outside.

I've double-checked and the static IP is still setup with a forwarding rule.

I've double-checked the google firewall and there's no rules specific to any IP.

I've tried creating a forwarding rule through the advanced load-balancing page (I don't think I should have to, but I tried as quick fix), but it never creates anything (goes back to the list with nothing added).

Is there anything else to check? A way to verify the forwarding rule is working?

Answer (score 0):

Forwarding rules work in conjunction with target pools and target instances to support load balancing and protocol forwarding features. It looks like that you're using forwarding rule with a target instance. You can use the following command to add a new forwarding rule to your target instance. For more information visit [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding/#addingforwardingrules).

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules create [FORWARDING_RULE]
[--address [ADDRESS]]
[--description [DESCRIPTION]]
[--ip-protocol [IP_PROTOCOL]]
[--ports [PORTS]
[--region [REGION]]
[--target-instance [TARGET_INSTANCE]]
[--target-instance-zone [TARGET_INSTANCE_ZONE]]
```

The other option is creating VM Instances with multiple network interfaces. Every interface can have an external IP address. This configuration is described in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces).